# Transfer MEW Wallet to Mist

Tags: mist, myetherwallet

I am new to Crypto. I made a new wallet on MyEtherWallet sometime ago. But, now i want to move that wallet to Mist.

One way to do this would be to just create a new mist wallet and transfer my ether from old wallet to new wallet. But, i was wondering if there is a way where i can actually move the wallet itself to Mist. So, end result would be that my new wallet in mist would have the same public address as my current wallet in MEW.

Can someone help out? Am i even thinking about it in the right way?

Comment: Agree with duplicate. You need to convert your plain private key to keystore file. You can do this via geth, or the MyEtherWallet Chrome Extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/myetherwallet/nlbmnnijcnlegkjjpcfjclmcfggfefdm (add your wallet, create password, go to your wallets, view, and download the keystore file. Don't forget the password!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by pasting the UTC keystore file in the Mist Keystore folder.

In Linux: You Have to paste the Keystore file in /home/$username/.ethereum/keystore

In Windows: In mist installation folder you can find the Keystore folder, there you have to paste

After Pasting this you can see the wallet address on the Accounts page of Mist Wallet.